# Copying / Cloning an ActiveStorage attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage, activemodel

I want to clone an attached image to another model.  Either as:

1. a reference, such that the attachment won't be deleted until all the referring objects are deleted
2. by cloning the attachment and having it as a distinct replica...

How does rails handle ActiveStorage attachments? Do they get deleted automatically when the model goes or does it need to be done manually? Is there a reference counting mechanism?

Comment: whats the rails version you are using?

Comment: Sorry, rails 6.0.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me in Rails 6.1.3

```ruby
model
  .new_file
  .attach(io: StringIO.new(original_file.download),
          filename: original_file.filename,
          content_type: original_file.content_type)
```